# Can Ktor have different log levels per package/file

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, logback, ktor

In spring boot, it's possible to specify a different log level at the package or even file level.

```
logging.level.com.company.project.monitors=DEBUG
logging.level.com.company.project.controllers=INFO
logging.level.com.company.project.controllers.utils=WARN
```

Is there anything similar in Ktor where we can set different logging for individual areas of the app (without writing a bunch of code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe isn't Spring Boot specific feature as such, but of the underlying logging library both Spring Boot and Ktor use by default.

In order to achieve the same behaviour in Ktor, add the following lines to your `logback.xml` file:

```xml
<logger name="com.company.project.monitors" level="DEBUG" />
<logger name="com.company.project.controllers" level="INFO" />
<logger name="com.company.project.controllers.utils" level="WARN" />
```

The `logback.xml` should be located in your `src/main/resources` directory, if you're using Gradle as your build tool.

You can read more about Logback support in Ktor here: https://ktor.io/docs/logging.html#add_dependencies